Casting(?) void pointers
I'm using void pointers to handle data in arrays, and i was wondering if i could cast(?) the data in a way that doesn't pad the code.
For example i have a structure:
typedef struct Matrix{
int rows;
int cols;
void **pMatrix;
} Matrix;

After allocating it if i want to fill it with either int data of double data i do:
Matrix *data_matrix(Matrix *mtrx, void *data, int filler, int data_type){
/*Data type 0 = int, 1 = double*/
for (int x = 0; x < mtrx -> rows; x++){
    for (int y = 0; y < mtrx -> cols; y++){
        if(data_type == 0){
            ((int **)mtrx -> pMatrix)[x][y] = ((int *)data)[(mtrx -> cols * x) + y];
        }
        else if(data_type == 1){
            ((double **)mtrx -> pMatrix)[x][y] = ((double *)data)[(mtrx -> cols * x) + y];
        }
    }
}
return mtrx;
}

My question is if there is a way to join the data type, something like ((data_type == 0) ? (int **) : (double **)? (also what is doing (type) before a variable called, i didn't know how to search it?)

Yes, that’s called casting. What are you doing with the matrix that benefits from having matrices with both types of entries be the same struct type, as opposed to having IntMatrix and DoubleMatrix? (Note that they can both embed a shared struct type with int rows; int cols; for certain common functionality, and if you call this base struct Matrix then it’s valid to cast between IntMatrix* and Matrix*.)

You might consider using a union, or a macro if you just want to save typing.

Thank you! i just wanted to make things as general as possible, i'm doing a jpg decoder and use the matrix structure to handle other type of data but i guess that separating them by type makes it easier to read

i'll look into that, thanks!

"After allocating it" How would you allocate the memory if you don't know in advance what you are storing in it? int and double aren't likely to be of same size.

i allocate space for a bunch of void pointers, first for rows (mtrx -> pMatrix = malloc(sizeof(void *) * rows);) then for the columns (for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
mtrx -> pMatrix[i] = malloc(sizeof(void *) * cols);})

So, you reserve memory to store a pointer but you want to store a double then. On 32bit systems, a pointer might be 4 byte and a double 8 bytes. You do not want to store void* but int or double in your example.

You are right! i think the solution is to allocate the data too, something along this answer, thank you!
